# how to put range and radio button in alert prompt in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Using Ionic2 and angular2:**

I want to create an alert box having range selector with numbers and radio button. Help?

Comment: thats not possible with [alerts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert)..perhaps try [modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals) or [popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#popovers)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into these 2 things and try to combine them in alertController.

1. [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)
2. [Range](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/)

**NOTE:** Not sure if combining `<ion-range>` with alertOptions will work.  Let me know your findings. If this cannot be done, you need to do this in [modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals).

**EDIT:** This does not work. You need to use modal and implement it separately.

Comment: this two things not working simultaneously with alert option. I have done this with modal and then its working. thank You!

Comment: Sure. A good learning. I also thought it might not work. It would have been nice if it did work together.

Comment: Could you please close this question then?